# Google App Engine recursive ndb.StructuredProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

I'm using Google App Engine for my backend development and I'm using datastore models and Google Cloud Storage to store my image objects. So here's my Media model

```
class Media(ndb.Model):

    url = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)  # url generated by images.get_serving_url
    path = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)  # path in GCP
    width = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)
    height = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)
    size = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

And now I also want to upload image thumbnail and store it in the same entity. So what I want is something like

```
class Media(ndb.Model):
    ...

    thumnail = ndb.LocalStructuredProperty(Media)
```

But Python doesn't let me to use self class as an argument for class attribute and GAE doesn't allow model names as `modelclass` argument for `ndb.StructuredProperty`.

I'm wondering, is there any way to avoid this limitation like lazy initialization or something like that?

Comment: You could just add the property to the class after the class definition.

`Media.thumnail = ndb.LocalStructuredProperty(Media)`

Comment: I don't think that's a good solution, because ndb.Model has a metaclass which does some binding work during model initialization, so I will have to do it by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class Media(ndb.Model):
    url = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    path = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    width = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)
    height = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)
    size = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class Thumbnail(Media):
    pass

class FullSize(Media):
    thumbnail = ndb.LocalStructuredProperty(Thumbnail)
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about such solution, I was hoping that there is a way to do it without creating separate model. I will mark you answer as a correct one, if nobody finds a better answer